# Netbeans 20 - Unable to install Python

Tags: python, plugins, netbeans

Netbeans 20 does not include Python in the library of plugins. I have downloaded it manually both in windows zip and netbeans python-RELEASE170-1.0.nbm. However, when I try to install this I get this:

Some plugins require plugin Navigate To Test to be installed.
The plugin Navigate To Test is requested in implementation version 17-ac2b269fa33a277ff09bc424fb9a5a8c63ed2194.  The following plugin is affected:       Python

Some plugins require plugin Code Coverage Support to be installed.
The plugin Code Coverage Support is requested in implementation version 17-ac2b269fa33a277ff09bc424fb9a5a8c63ed2194.  The following plugin is affected:       Python

Some plugins require plugin Common Test Runner UI to be installed.
The plugin Common Test Runner UI is requested in implementation version 17-ac2b269fa33a277ff09bc424fb9a5a8c63ed2194.  The following plugin is affected:       P

and the Next button grayed out.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a known bug: https://github.com/albilu/netbeansPython/issues/88

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem
Your plugin is for NetBeans 19 and you are installing it in 20.
My solution for this is to change your NetBeans version to build the desired plugin.